# Why is my second GPU not being utilized on multiple monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-settings

I have 2 [Nvidia GTX770 EVGA Video cards with 4GB](https://www.evga.com/Products/Specs/GPU.aspx?pn=2CFDED16-58B6-4782-BA63-B83C32CDF97F)

But when I watch videos on multiple screens, [image: Task Manger showing only GPU 1 being used while GPU 0 does no work]

These are my Nvidia settings

[image: Nvidia Settings - drivers up-to-date]

Why does only one video card show utilization?

More importantly, how can I make Windows 10 use both cards to maximize power on my 4 monitors?

Comment: “Why does only one video card show utilization?” - SLI is disabled.  Your browser and/or video player is only going to use a single GPU.  You either have to enable SLI to use both GPUs symotanously or use the DX12/Vulcan appropriate feature set that  allows you to use two different GPUs

Comment: Each video card has 2 monitors plugged into it, shouldn't each video card be responsible for powering 2 monitors? seems like only one video card is working for all 4 monitors - I don't get it

Comment: They are responsible for the desktop just not the application.  Chrome/Firefox/Edge can’t use multiple GPUs (nor SLI/Crossfire) although you can force that to happen through the appropriate control panel.  Likewise HTML5 isn’t DX12/Vulcan

Comment: So how can I force Windows 10 make use of both cards to maximize power on my 4 monitors? (I'm planning to upgrade to 8 screens and I know one card can handle 4 monitors alone)

Comment: There is no required connection between what GPU does work and what display it is shown us. If you want to do computation on both GPUs, enable SLI.

Comment: @Drace Like I said, enable SLI, my commentary was submitted to share important knowledge

Comment: @Ramhound can you please put together your comments as an answer so I can award it to you.. thanks for the help in understanding!